# How to get a substring based on index of another string

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I need to extract the integer value from some log files. The integer value always appears after a substring `return code`. But it may or may not have additional stuff after this substring. Below are two example entries:

```
Job with id 0 ended with status COMPLETED, return code 16, in 1 minute 12 seconds 
Job with id 0 COMPLETED with return code 255
```

So, here I want 16 in the first case, and 255 in the second case.

My initial approach was to use awk - but the column in which the required value occurs is not consistent; so it failed.

How do I achieve this in a reliable manner?

Comment: Yes, it will only appear once. The above two lines are the only way it can appear in these log files (I confirmed this by checking the program that writes this log line)

Comment: And it's always `code` followed by some digits? Would Perl instead of shell scripting also be possible?

Comment: yes. code followed by digits. After the digits, there may or may not be content. perl is ok, I can collect the output into a variable in my bash script I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash

strings=('Job with id 0 ended with status COMPLETED, return code 16, in 1 minute 12 seconds'
         'Job with id 0 COMPLETED with return code 255'
        )

for string in "${strings[@]}" ; do
    code=${string#*return code }
    code=${code%%[!0-9]*}
    echo $code
done
```

`#` removes pattern from the left, `%` from the right.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for me as a pure bash solution.

Comment: btw, I assume you meant to say `*` from the right (instead of `%`)

Comment: @Bajal: Actually, no. `*` is a wildcard that matches anything. See *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood. It is clear to me now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Using perl a solution using regexp could be:

`perl -ne  'print "$2\n" if m/(code )(\d*)/' a.txt`

This prints the numbers `16`and `255` to stdout, each on a separate line (`\n`). Here `a.txt`contains the two lines

```
Job with id 0 ended with status COMPLETED, return code 16, in 1 minute 12 seconds
Job with id 0 COMPLETED with return code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` version:

```
sed -e 's/.*return code \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' logfile.txt
```

It removes everything from the line except the digits immediately following `return code`.

or, using extended regexps with GNU sed:

```
sed -r -e 's/.*return code ([0-9]+).*/\1/' logfile.txt
```

NOTE: some versions of `sed` use `-E` rather than `-r` to enable extended regular expressions.

Also note these `sed` scripts will print unchanged any lines that don't match the regular expression.  If that's not what you want, use `sed`'s `-n` option and the `p` command to print only matching lines, e.g.:

```
sed -n -r -e 's/.*return code ([0-9]+).*/\1/p' logfile.txt
```